# Call text file to populate paragraph in HTML - Is it possible?

Tags: javascript, html

Is it possible to call a text file similarily to how you would reference an image in a image tag? Similar to

```
<img src="http://link.to/image.png">
```

but

```
<p src="http://link.to/text.txt"></p>
```

?

Can you do this with javascript? Any advice would be super appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with XHR (XMLHttpRequest) . Pure Javascript:

```
<p id="text"></p>

<script>
text = document.getElementById('text');

xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("GET", "http://link.to/file.txt");
xhr.send();

xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhr.readyState == 4)               //the readyState if the status of the request 
        text.innerHTML = xhr.responseText; // (http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_xmlhttprequest_onreadystatechange.asp)
                                           // 4 is a completed request
}
</script>
```

Or, jQuery has the `.load()` function:

```
<p id="text"></p>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
$('#text').load('http://link.to/file.txt');
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can load the remote content via [AJAX](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/AJAX), as long as the remote server sends you proper [CORS headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS).

Something like this should work:

```
var $p = document.getElementsByTagName('p')[0];
var url = $p.getAttribute('src');
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.onreadystatechange = function insertContents() { 
  if (xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status === 200) {
    $p.innerHTML = xhr.responseText;
  }
};
xhr.open('GET', url);
xhr.send();
```

Answer (score 0):

possible with ajax

```
<p data-src="http://link.to/text.txt"></p>
```

JS:

```
$('p').each(function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    $.ajax({
        url: $this.data('src'),
        dataType: "text",
        success: function (data) {
           $this.html(data);
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var client = new XMLHttpRequest();
client.open('GET', 'text.txt');
client.onreadystatechange = function() {
  alert(client.responseText);
}
client.send();
```

Comment: Also there is a document https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/wiki/How-to-run-things-locally , which can help you do this

Answer (score -1):

You can display text file using IFrame. Like this-

Comment: <IFRAME src="textFile.txt"/>